# Gerrit - Replicating repos to github

Tags: github, gerrit

My configuration for replication.config is:

```
[remote "github"]
    url = git@github.com:organization/${name}.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/tags/*
    threads = 3
    timeout = 30
    remoteNameStyle = dash
```

From ~gerrit/.ssh, I can ssh -T git@github.com successfully. After running "ssh -p 29418 hostname replication start --wait --all", there are errors:

`Replicate <repo name> ref ..all.. to github.com, FAILED!`

However, there's no error in replication_log file, it shows: `Replication to git@github.com:**started...
Created remote repository:***`

Comment: Does the repo name contain a `/`?

Comment: @StephenKing Yes, the repo name contains /

Comment: Then I suggest to have a look at the [replication plugin's documentation](https://review.typo3.org/plugins/replication/Documentation/config.html) and the `remote.NAME.remoteNameStyle` option there. This allows you to replace slashes in the name, which cannot be used with Github.